# Why do some flags take so much longer than others to resolve?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442713/prove-at-least-one-of-the-following-with-the-squeeze-theorem) as an unclear question a few hours ago. I raised the same flag later on [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442892/log-equation-help), and it was resolved within a few minutes.

I'm curious to know what goes on behind the scenes to generate the difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the questions are put in [Close Review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) where reviewers vote to close them or to leave open.

Additionally, questions may get some close votes directly, not via review.

Your flag is resolved as helpful provided that at least one close vote is cast with the reason you picked. When that happens depends on how busy the queue is, how active the site is in general, and whether reviewers find the cause for closing valid.